# Copy Excel chart as picture and paste to range in other sheet

Tags: excel, charts, copy-paste, vba

I've been trying below code to copy chart as picture, and paste it in another sheet without selection/activate. however it does not seem to paste the picture into the range:

```
Dim Range_DriverLookup As Range, RowCounter_DriverLookup As Long
Dim Count_DeliveredServicesNumber As Long, Counter_DeliveredServicesNumber As Long
Dim Cht_SitePotential As ChartObject
Dim Cht_Top5 As ChartObject
Dim Cht_RegionalPeerGroup As ChartObject
Dim PvtTbl_SitePotential As PivotTable
Dim PvtTbl_Top5 As PivotTable
Dim PvtTbl_RegionalPeerGroup As PivotTable
Dim Graph_PerformanceReport As Excel.Picture

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Assign ranges, pivottables and charts '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set Range_DriverLookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetDriverLookup.Name).ListObjects("DriverLookup").DataBodyRange
Set PvtTbl_SitePotential = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReportLookup.Name).PivotTables("PivotTableSitePotential")
Set PvtTbl_Top5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReportLookup.Name).PivotTables("PivotTableTop5")
Set PvtTbl_RegionalPeerGroup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReportLookup.Name).PivotTables("PivotTableRegionalPeerGroup")
Set Cht_SitePotential = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReportLookup.Name).ChartObjects("ChartSitePotential")
Set Cht_Top5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReportLookup.Name).ChartObjects("ChartTop5")
Set Cht_RegionalPeerGroup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReportLookup.Name).ChartObjects("ChartRegionalPeerGroup")

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Initiate new performance report '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'// Clear previous graphs
For Each Graph_PerformanceReport In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReport.Name).Pictures
    Graph_PerformanceReport.Delete
Next Graph_PerformanceReport
'// Clear previous sheet setup, and initiate new
Stop
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReport.Name)
    '/ Unhide rows in PerformanceReport
    .Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    '/ Clear previous "table of content"
    .Range("TableOfContent").ClearContents
    '/ Reset pagebreaks and set for new frontpage
    .ResetAllPageBreaks
    .Rows(71).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
End With

'// Set filters on frontpage graph
PvtTbl_SitePotential.ClearAllFilters
PvtTbl_SitePotential.PivotFields("Serviceline").AutoSort Order:=xlDescending, Field:="Potential Savings (Yearly) "
PvtTbl_SitePotential.PivotFields("Serviceline").ShowDetail = False
PvtTbl_SitePotential.PivotFields("Site").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReport.Name).Range("Site").Value
PvtTbl_SitePotential.PivotFields("Serviceline").PivotFilters.Add _
Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo, DataField:=PvtTbl_SitePotential.PivotFields("Potential Savings (Yearly) "), Value1:=5000

'// Create title for frontpage graph
With Cht_SitePotential.Chart.ChartTitle
        .Caption = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReport.Name).Range("Site") & " - Yearly Potential on Service Level"
End With

'// Paste frontpagegraph to PerformanceReport
With Cht_SitePotential.Chart
    .ChartArea.Copy
End With
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReport.Name).Range("D7:D7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Edited with larger part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'ts working for me when I simulated `.Range("Frontpage_Graph")` with `"P1:P1"`

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReport.Name).Range("P1:P1").PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
```

`ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` will give a better resolution chart picture.

If you use a range like `"P10:Z20"` it will just use **P10** as the anchor point of the Chart picture.

Comment: When I try to use `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` instead, it gives me "variable not defined"

Comment: @SebastianKoefoed can you post the rest of thei `Sub` code ? if you change back to my line with `xlPasteValues` at the end, do you get an error ?

Comment: I have added all the code until the pasting part. I get no errors with `xlPasteValues`

Comment: @SebastianKoefoed try putting it in brackets `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetPerformanceReport.Name).Range("P1:P1").PasteSpecial (ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)`

Comment: I removed the name given to the cell pasting the picture, and it now works with `xlPastevalues`, however still not working with `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile`

Comment: I am not getting this error, still no luck simulating it

Comment: `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile`  is PowerPoint enum value.